# Deleting seconds in a timestamp format - php

Tags: php, time

I am trying to convert some date 'date' (created with current_timestamp()), and displaying 2013-02-13 17:38:08, and I don't want the seconds to appear. But when I use `date('Y-m-d H:i', $date)`, I get

```
1970-01-01 01:33
```

I think I am not using the right php methods, someone could help ?

Best,
Mehdi

Comment: Look at your errors. Assumed constant `date`

Comment: sorry, I have edited my post

Comment: then see the answer provided by Rusty Faucet. Edit: oh you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) accepts a parameter as a timestamp, so use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert first:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($date))
```

might it just be easier to use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)?